# How to avoid multiple map functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have two objects. First one have entire school full details of students record. Example like

```
var first = {
 students: 
    [
     { id:'1', name:"suresh", age:"20", degree:"BSc", status:"obsent"},
     { id:'2', name:"ramesh", age:"21", degree:"BCom", status:"present"},
     { id:'3', name:"rajesh", age:"19", degree:"BA", status:"leave"},
     { id:'4', name:"satish", age:"28", degree:"BL", status:"obsent"}
   ]
}
```

Second one have particular class students information about the status of the student for that day. Example like

```
var second ={
 students: 
    [
     { id:'1',status:"present"},
     { id:'12',status:"obsent"},
     { id:'3',status:"obsent"},
     { id:'14',status:"leave"}
    ]
}
```

Now I need to compare the student id and need to display the status based on the result. I have achieved in the following way.

```
 items = first.students.map(function(item){
      status =item.status;
      second.students.map(function(key){
         if(key.id == item.id) { status = key.status }
      });
      return "<tr><td>"+item.name+"</td><td>"+item.age+"</td><td>"+item.degree+"</td><td>"+status+"</td></tr>";
  });

  $('table#main tbody').html(items);
```

The above code is working fine. But if you look at my code, I have used the map functionality multiple times. I feel that I have done something wrong in the performance wise. Is that possible to reduce using the map twice or any other better way to achieve the same result. Please suggest me.

**Code Snippet**

```js
var first = {
  students: 
  [
   { id:'1', name:"suresh", age:"20", degree:"BSc", status:"obsent"},
   { id:'2', name:"ramesh", age:"21", degree:"BCom", status:"present"},
   { id:'3', name:"rajesh", age:"19", degree:"BA", status:"leave"},
   { id:'4', name:"satish", age:"28", degree:"BL", status:"obsent"}
  ]
}
var second ={
  students: 
  [
   { id:'1',status:"present"},
   { id:'12',status:"obsent"},
   { id:'3',status:"obsent"},
   { id:'14',status:"leave"}
  ]
}

items = first.students.map(function(item){
   status =item.status;
   second.students.map(function(key){
      if(key.id == item.id) { status = key.status }
   });
   return "<tr><td>"+item.name+"</td><td>"+item.age+"</td><td>"+item.degree+"</td><td>"+status+"</td></tr>";
});

$('table#main tbody').html(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Degree</th>
    <th>Stauts</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complexity will be better if you build an object which keys are `id` and values are `status` from `second.students` then you update `status` in  `first.students` based on this object:

```js
var first = {
  students: 
  [
   { id:'1', name:"suresh", age:"20", degree:"BSc", status:"obsent"},
   { id:'2', name:"ramesh", age:"21", degree:"BCom", status:"present"},
   { id:'3', name:"rajesh", age:"19", degree:"BA", status:"leave"},
   { id:'4', name:"satish", age:"28", degree:"BL", status:"obsent"}
  ]
}
var second ={
  students: 
  [
   { id:'1',status:"present"},
   { id:'12',status:"obsent"},
   { id:'3',status:"obsent"},
   { id:'14',status:"leave"}
  ]
}

var statusById= second.students.reduce(function(m, e) {
    m[e.id] = e.status; 
    return m;
}, {});    

items = first.students.map(function(item){
   item.status = statusById[item.id] || item.status;
   return "<tr><td>"+item.name+"</td><td>"+item.age+"</td><td>"+item.degree+"</td><td>"+item.status+"</td></tr>";
});

$('table#main tbody').html(items);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="main" cellspacing="2" border="1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Degree</th>
    <th>Stauts</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.

Answer (score 4):

Due to the way your objects are set up, it looks like that will be `O(n)` time for the lookup, because you need to loop through the first student array for every student id.

To get around this, you can do a single map where you assign the id as the key of a new intermediate object in the format of:

`x = {1: {...}, 2: {...}}`

From there, you can now do constant time `O(1)` lookups:

`x[id]`

The only extra work is building the intermediate hash, but that will be less computation than what you have above.

See this example below. Note that it does use 2 maps, but it's different than your example because it's not a map within a map which is exponential:

```
var students = [
  { id:'1', name:"suresh", age:"20", degree:"BSc", status:"obsent"},
  { id:'2', name:"ramesh", age:"21", degree:"BCom", status:"present"},
  { id:'3', name:"rajesh", age:"19", degree:"BA", status:"leave"},
  { id:'4', name:"satish", age:"28", degree:"BL", status:"obsent"}
];

var studentIds = {};
students.forEach(function(student) {
  studentIds[student.id] = {name: student.name, age: student.age, degree: student.degree, status: student.status}
});

var second = [
  { id:'1',status:"present"},
  { id:'12',status:"obsent"},
  { id:'3',status:"obsent"},
  { id:'14',status:"leave"}
];

var studentStatuses = second.map(function(student) {
  // do whatever you have to do here
  return (studentIds[student.id] || {}).status;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.